# How can I recover my MS Word preferences and macros after a Windows 10 update?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, windows-update

I've scripted some MS Word macros that I use daily, and I've set a lot of preferences in the program: styles, ribbon customization, etc. Yesterday (10/7/2019) Windows 10 updated itself. Now, all my macros and preferences are gone. **Is there a way to recover them?**

I did find 2 copies of Normal.dotm:

1. The older Normal.dotm, from February 9, 2019, is in C:\Users\brett\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.
2. The newer Normal.dotm, from October 7, 2019, is in C:\Users\brett\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates

I thought one of those might store either my preferences or my macros or both. However, the dates of those files don't match the dates of my changes.

- October 7, 2019 is the date that the Windows 10 update happened.
- A few days before that, I'd made changes to one of my macros.
- A few weeks before that, I customized my Quick Access toolbar.
- I don't know what February 9, 2019 is.

Anyway, I'd just like to recover all the customization I did and the macros I created. Thanks!

Comment: Your settings if it’s within 15 days would exist in the same directory within Windows.old you will have to forcefully take ownership of the folder.  If it’s been more than 15 days, or you already removed the previous install through Disk Cleanup then they are gone forever.  With that said there is no guarantee the file is even there (that’s just the location based on the current location) where it would exist.  Look there then edit and update your question

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but I did a search within This PC for "Windows.old", and got 2 irrelevant results.

Comment: That means the files no longer exist